# Open and close excel file via task scheduler with AD user

Tags: excel, batch-file, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

Background info: [Automatically run data connections in XLSM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398444/automatically-run-data-connections-in-xlsm)

I have a batch script which logs a start and end time, and runs a VBS scripts, which in turn opens up a excel file, runs a couple of data connections and closes the file again.

This works just fine when I run the batch script. However when I run it through the task scheduler the data connections are not run on the excel file. It seems like it might be related to some sort of security issue, but I cant figure out what the issue is exactly.

In the eventviewer of the server I was setting this up I found this little message:

> The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation
>   permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
>   {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} and APPID  Unavailable to the
>   user DOMAIN\USER SID
>   (S-1-5-21-3431573511-3352521975-2604885492-32293) from address
>   LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container
>   Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be
>   modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

But I have no idea what this means.

Answer (score 0):

This error is being logged into the System event logs in Event Viewer due to inadequate permission for the farm admin account on the DCOM component 000C101C-0000-0000-C000-000000000046. In order to change the permission settings, perform the following steps:

1. Open Component Service by clicking *Start → Administrative Tools → Component Services*.
2. Navigate and expand the node *Component Services → Computers → My Computer → DCOM Config*.
3. Right-click the sub node *“000C101C-0000-0000-C000-000000000046”* and select *“Properties”*.
4. On the Properties dialog box, select Security tab. In most cases you will notice that the settings are grayed out. This is because the logged in user doesn't have enough permissions on this component to change the settings. In order to provide this permissions, perform the steps described in next section *“Change Component Service Owner and Permission”*. You may need to restart the server after doing this.
5. Once you set up the permission mentioned in previous step, in the Launch and Activation Permissions section in Security tab, select Customize option and click Edit.
6. In the popup window, add the farm admin user account and check Local Launch and Local Activation permissions.
7. Restart IIS and SP Timer. If possible, restart the server itself.

Reference: [http://sajiviswam.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/the-machine-default-permission-settings-do-not-grant-local-activation-permission-for-the-com-server-application-with-clsid-000c101c-0000-0000-c000-000000000046-sharepoint-2010/](https://sajiviswam.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/the-machine-default-permission-settings-do-not-grant-local-activation-permission-for-the-com-server-application-with-clsid-000c101c-0000-0000-c000-000000000046-sharepoint-2010/)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when trying saving an Excel file via a Powershell script.  I wasn't able to adjust the security settings for CLSID “000C101C-0000-0000-C000-000000000046”, which should resolve this, so I ran the task under the SYSTEM account, which already had the necessary permissions.  This resolved the issue.